# In this for loop, how to capture both messages instead of just first one? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, each

So I'm trying to accomplish the following

- Loop through all the td's with class of manager-msg
- Save the text from each of those into a variable/array
- Do a split and create new text
- Replace the text of each manager-msg td

Currently I'm stuck on the first part, I'm able to loop through twice in my example [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/xmdcG).

However I saves the first message twice, does get the text in the 2nd td.

[image]

[image]

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="10" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Wants to Meet</td>
    <td >Message</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ann</td>
    <td>Cal</td>
    <td class="manager-msg">Hi I'd love to meet Cal</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bob</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td class="manager-msg">Hi I'd like to meet Joe</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var home_inbox_br_fix = function() {
    var num_manager_msg = $('.manager-msg').length;
    var test = [];

    for (var i = 0, num_manager_msg; i < num_manager_msg; i++) {
        test[i] = $('.manager-msg').html();
        alert('Message '+(i+1));
        alert(test);
  console.log(test);
    }
};

/*
var home_inbox_br_fix = function() {
    var test = [];
    $(".manager-msg").each(function(i){
        test.push($('.manager-msg').html());
        alert(this.id + " is the " + i + "th div with this class");
    });
    console.log(test);
};
*/

home_inbox_br_fix();
```

Got code tunnel at the moment X( how would you guys handle this?

Comment: What's the point, just to alert the two names -> http://jsfiddle.net/m6P3B/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead using jQuery [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
var home_inbox_br_fix = function() {
    var test = [];
    $('.manager-msg').each(function(i){
        test[i] = this.innerHTML;
  alert(test[i]);
    });
};
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EsvL8/)

Comment: @Leon, sometimes its nice for me too when other people look at my code :)

Comment: Yea :) it's like talking it out, broken through this bottle neck, now on to some multi-dimensional arrays

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the values.

```
var messages = $('.manager-msg').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YfpZL/

Comment: Thanks! I forgot `this` me = 'need more sleep'

Answer (score 1):

You're always getting the same text because you're not using the current index when getting the HTML. It will work if you loop like this (although there are other ways, as shown in the other answers):

```
for (var i = 0, num_manager_msg; i < num_manager_msg; i++) {
    test[i] = $('.manager-msg').eq(i).html();
    // You were missing this! -----^
    alert('Message '+(i+1));
    alert(test[i]);
    console.log(test[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need proper indexing

```
var home_inbox_br_fix = function() {
    var num_manager_msg = $('.manager-msg').length;
    var test = [];

    for (var i = 0, num_manager_msg; i < num_manager_msg; i++) {
        test[i] = ($($('.manager-msg')[i]).html());
        alert('Message '+(i+1));
        alert(test);
        console.log(test);
    }
};
```